# Combining distributions

Tags: distributions, measurement, aggregation

I have a ruler and a set of poles $S$. My ruler is not perfect, so a length measurement of one pole yields in fact a sample of a probability distribution (e.g. natural scientists usually find normal distributions), so I have a set of PDFs: $P=\{p_s : s\in S\}$. Now for a subset $A\subseteq S$, I'd like to know the following:

- (estimated) total length of poles in $A$
- a PDF for a "model pole" representing $A$

I have some intuition that total length distribution could be given by convolution (and then total could be a mean of that) and the "model pole" could be defined as conflation.

Do I reason properly? Maybe there is a better method. e.g. by using some properties of PDF stored in $P$ (e.g. by creating a conflation we could argue that there exists some prior distribution of lengths)?

Comment: Scientists might *say* they find normal distributions, but lengths cannot actually be normally distributed.

Comment: Agree. In this problem you can assume that we _know_ how the length distribution for each pole looks like and now we want to use this result to estimate the total length of a specified subset.